# Invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "mc"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to get an item "manufacturer" with an array of contacts and each contact contains an array of translations using this query

```
SELECT m.* FROM manufacturers m
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT ARRAY (
      SELECT mc.* FROM manufacturers_contacts mc
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ARRAY (
              SELECT ct.* FROM contact_trans ct
              WHERE ct.manufacturers_contacts_id = mc.id
              ) AS translations
          ) ct ON mc.id = ct.manufacturers_contacts_id
    WHERE mc.manufacturers_id = m.id
    ) AS contacts
  ) mc ON m.id = mc.manufacturers_id
WHERE id = $1
```

but I get this error

```
invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "mc"
```

this is the ER diagram

[image]

dummy data example:

```
{
    "name": "Manufacturer 1 DE",
    "address":  "Address 1 DE",
    "zipCode": "12345",
    "country": "DE",
    "hotline": "12345678",
    "serviceTime": "ser time",
    "contacts":    [{
            "name": "contact 1",
            "phoneNumber":  "phone Number 1",
            "email": "email@1.com",
            "translations":  [{
                            "language": "de",
                            "content": "function 1 DE",
                        }, {
                            "language": "en",
                            "content": "function 1 EN",
                        }]
        }]
}
```

I tried to change the structure of the query to solve it but I wasn't able to fix it.

Since I don't have much experience with complex SQL queries, I won't know what is the right way to do this?

Comment: can you add data types pls of those attributes? are those json fields? or just plain strings/numbers ? also It would be great if you shared the DDL and some dummy data ..

Comment: all strings (varchar) except the ids

I edited the question with dummy data

Comment: You have the alias `mc` used in two different places to refer to two different things: 1) As alias for `manufacturers_contacts` and 2) As alias for the `LEFT JOIN` query. I'm guessing that is where `invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "mc"` is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nested queries inside joins can't access the tables outside, you must use `LATERAL` joins for it.

as for your dummy data example: to select non-table-like result the JSONB functions as useful

here, the code that selects the structure you need (result is json):

```sql
SELECT to_jsonb(data.*) FROM (
  SELECT m.*, c.contacts
   FROM manufacturers AS m
   LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
     SELECT jsonb_agg(x.*) AS contacts FROM (
        SELECT mc.*, tr.function
          FROM manufacturers_contacts AS mc
          LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
            SELECT jsonb_agg(z.*) AS function FROM (
              SELECT ct.*
               FROM contact_trans AS ct
              WHERE ct.manufacturers_contacts_id = mc.id
            ) AS z
          ) AS tr ON TRUE
         WHERE mc.manufacturers_id = m.id
      ) AS x
   ) AS c ON TRUE
  WHERE m.id = $1
) AS data;
```

Comment: The data is not json, the data is in a relational database, the example above is just an illustration of what the returned row should look like

Comment: but mentioning LATERAL is useful

Comment: json - is just the output format for complex result

Answer (score 1):

You indents are strange -- here they are normalized

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM manufacturers m
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT ARRAY (
    SELECT mc.* 
    FROM manufacturers_contacts mc
    LEFT JOIN ( 
      SELECT ARRAY (
        SELECT ct.* 
        FROM contact_trans ct
        WHERE ct.manufacturers_contacts_id = mc.id
      ) AS translations
    ) ct ON mc.id = ct.manufacturers_contacts_id
    WHERE mc.manufacturers_id = m.id
  ) AS contacts
) sub ON m.id = sub.manufacturers_id
WHERE id = $1
```

I also changed the final alias to something other than "mc" -- does this give you an error?

Comment: it's clearer but it gives the same exact error 
```
✖ invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "mc"
```

 (and I learned that using the same alias was a mistake from my side)